# Monerod Deterministic build

Tags: monerod, build

Is it possible to build monerod deterministically ?

If not, is there any technical limitation specific to monero ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing yet, but is a a long wanted goal.

Progress along those lines was made in the last few months, with an automated build system based on Travis, maintained by a contributor under the username 'pigeons'.

I do not know of a timeline for future steps towards deterministic builds, though.